# Android Emulator is not running

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-launcher

Hi I am new in android and started to learn

I have Windows 7 PC, with 2.33GHz Intel Core I3.

I am using Eclipse SDK

Version: 4.2.2
Build id: M20130204-1200

Android Development Toolkit

Version: 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508

I have tried to run simple hello world program and don't know but emulator is showing just 
android----- android, it's not even starting it's main windows

can anybody help me how to resolve that issue

Comment: You just wait..It takes a lot of time for the emulator to start..Make sure that snapshot is checked while creating the new `avd` and next time when you launch the `avd` make sure the `Launch from snapshot` checkbox is checked..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally suggest you instead of use of Android Emulator use

[GenyMotion](http://www.genymotion.com/)  or [BlueStacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/) in both of them

for just android application development and testing [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) is the best best and the best

Answer (score 1):

first time emulator start takes soo long, i mean first time ever, and first time in day.
however, you can check the Logcat and see what is going on,

you can view logcat (if not already appearing) by going to 
Window -> Show View -> Logcat
if does not appear in the list, click other, and search for logcat.

once emulator started it will show log in logcat window.
it might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You should try the x86 version of the emulator, with HAXM enabled (if your computer supports Intel VT) it will be much faster than the ARM version.
Then, when creating a new device, choose the Intel Atom (x86) option for its CPU.
[This is the guide I followed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13856866/1397117), looks like things haven't changed much since then.

Answer (score 0):

You just wait..It takes a lot of time for the emulator to start..Make sure that snapshot is checked while creating the new `avd` and next time when you launch the `avd` make sure the `Launch from snapshot` checkbox is checked..

Answer (score -1):

Android Emulators are very slow and buggy try GenyMotion it is fastest Emulator !
Every Android Developer should have.

Comment: While potentially useful, this doesnt help fix @Kinjal issue.